# How can I pass a parameter from Razor into the service worker file for a PWA?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, progressive-web-apps

I'm creating a PWA (Progressive Web App), and am registering my service worker in my view:

```
    if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('@Url.Content("~/sw.js")', { scope: '@Url.Content("~/")' })
          .then(function(registration) {
            console.log('G081 Service Worker Registered');
          });
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
            console.log('G081 Service Worker Ready');
        });
    }
```

And one of the first things I do in my service worker is import the idb-keyval library, as follows:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    self.importScripts("/3971/lib/idb-keyval/idb-keyval-iife.min.js");
}());
```

All is is well with that. It's registered and running. However, you will notice in my `self.importScripts` function (in my service worker), I am hard-coding part of the path (`"3971/"`). I am doing this because of the branching strategy we use at my job. Every branch gets its own site on our test server (In my case it's 3971). As a result, I need to be able to tell my service worker to look in the sub-folder 3971 for the idb-keyval javascript file. If I don't tell it that, it looks in the parent folder and doesn't find it. And this will change again when we push to production. The app will then be at the site root, and will need to look for the javascript file without the "3971" sub-folder.

I am going to call this my scope folder. Essentially I need a way to tell my service worker which scope folder to use for resources. I'm doing something similar in my view page, as you see above, where I use Razor to serialize my scope folder to register my service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('@Url.Content("~/sw.js")', { scope: '@Url.Content("~/")' })
```

Renders to:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/3971/sw.js', { scope: '/3971/' }) // MY DYNAMIC BRANCH
// and ...
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', { scope: '/' }) // PRODUCTION
```

**Is there a way that I can pass a parameter into my service worker so that it knows which scope folder it is using?** For example, can I do something like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/3971/sw.js?scope=%2F3971%2F', { scope: '/3971/' }) // MY DYNAMIC BRANCH
```

**And then in my service worker, consume that parameter and use it to get my resource(s)?** Something like this:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    self.importScripts(param['scope'] + "lib/idb-keyval/idb-keyval-iife.min.js");
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get query params of the service worker path.

```
const scope = (new URLSearchParams(location.search)).get('scope');
```